# Joining up two sql tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've got two tables that contain the data:

```
GroupMembers
Users, GroupID

GroupPosts
GroupID,PostID
```

I want to get a table output that contains

```
Users, GroupID, PostID
```

Users can belong to multiple groups, and each group can have multiple posts. So I would like to have all users and every single post.

So if

```
GroupMembers:

+-------+---------+
| Users | GroupID |
+-------+---------+
| User1 | Group1  |
+-------+---------+
| User2 | Group1  |
+-------+---------+
| User2 | Group2  |
+-------+---------+
| User3 | Group2  |
+-------+---------+

GroupPosts

+---------+--------+
| GroupID | PostID |
+---------+--------+
| Group1  | Post1  |
+---------+--------+
| Group1  | Post2  |
+---------+--------+
| Group2  | Post1  |
+---------+--------+
| Group2  | Post4  |
+---------+--------+
```

Should return a table that contains

```
+-------+--------+-------+
| User  | Group  | Post  |
+-------+--------+-------+
| User1 | Group1 | Post1 |
+-------+--------+-------+
| User1 | Group1 | Post2 |
+-------+--------+-------+
| User2 | Group1 | Post1 |
+-------+--------+-------+
| User2 | Group1 | Post2 |
+-------+--------+-------+
| User2 | Group2 | Post1 |
+-------+--------+-------+
| User2 | Group2 | Post4 |
+-------+--------+-------+
| User3 | Group2 | Post1 |
+-------+--------+-------+
| User3 | Group2 | Post4 |
+-------+--------+-------+
```

I hope that makes sense?

appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple `JOIN` query, e.g.:

```
SELECT g.users, g.groupID, gp.postid
FROM GroupMembers g JOIN GroupPosts gp ON g.groupID = gp.groupID;
```

Answer (score 0):

People love using JOIN syntax and you may love it too, but I find it more readable with equals "oldschool" syntax:

```
select a.Users, a.GroupID, b.PostID 
from GroupMembers a, GroupPosts b where b.GroupID = a.GroupID;
```

Using JOIN would just involve something like JOIN ON b.GroupID = a.GroupID, I believe. :)

Answer (score 0):

Select m.users, m.groupid,p.groupid,p.postid

from GroupMembers as m

JOIN GroupPosts as p on m.groupid=p.groupid

On mobile so can't refer back to your post but I think that was it.